# deploying to heroku keeps installing sqlite3, but no sqlite3 as dependency in gemfile.lock, and no sqlite3 in gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, ubuntu-11.10

I know that I can't have sqlite3 when I deploy to heroku (I have used it in development, but since then deleted it.

```
 jeffrey@ubuntu5:~/Documents/Sites/burma_project$ bundle show sqlite3
 Could not find gem 'sqlite3' in the current bundle.
```

Also in my gemfile, there's no sqlite3 there

```
  gem 'rails', '3.1.1'
  gem 'activeadmin'
  gem 'builder'
  gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
  gem 'daemons'
  gem 'twilio-ruby'
  gem 'whenever', :require=> false
  gem 'gravatar_image_tag', '1.0.0.pre2'

 group :assets do
   gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'
   gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
   gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
 end

   group :development do
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
gem 'annotate', '2.4.0'
    #  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.4'
    #  gem 'localtunnel'
   end 

  group :production do
    #gem 'therubyracer-heroku', '0.8.1.pre3'
    gem 'pg'
  end

 gem 'jquery-rails'

   group :test do
     # Pretty printed test output
     gem 'turn', :require => false
     gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
     gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
     gem 'spork', '0.9.0.rc8'
     gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'
  end
```

Also in my gemfile.lock, I did control+f and could not find any gem that depended on sqlite3

Here is my gemfile.lock

```
GEM
remote: http://rubygems.org/
specs:
  actionmailer (3.1.1)
    actionpack (= 3.1.1)
    mail (~> 2.3.0)
  actionpack (3.1.1)
    activemodel (= 3.1.1)
    activesupport (= 3.1.1)
    builder (~> 3.0.0)
    erubis (~> 2.7.0)
    i18n (~> 0.6)
    rack (~> 1.3.2)
    rack-cache (~> 1.1)
    rack-mount (~> 0.8.2)
    rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
    sprockets (~> 2.0.2)
activeadmin (0.3.4)
  devise (>= 1.1.2)
  fastercsv
  formtastic (< 2.0.0)
  inherited_resources (< 1.3.0)
  kaminari (>= 0.12.4)
  meta_search (>= 0.9.2)
  rails (>= 3.0.0)
  sass (>= 3.1.0)
activemodel (3.1.1)
  activesupport (= 3.1.1)
  builder (~> 3.0.0)
  i18n (~> 0.6)
activerecord (3.1.1)
  activemodel (= 3.1.1)
  activesupport (= 3.1.1)
  arel (~> 2.2.1)
  tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
activeresource (3.1.1)
  activemodel (= 3.1.1)
  activesupport (= 3.1.1)
activesupport (3.1.1)
  multi_json (~> 1.0)
annotate (2.4.0)
ansi (1.4.1)
arel (2.2.1)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1-x86-mingw32)
builder (3.0.0)
chronic (0.6.7)
coffee-rails (3.1.1)
  coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
  railties (~> 3.1.0)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
  coffee-script-source
  execjs
coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
daemons (1.1.8)
delayed_job (3.0.1)
  activesupport (~> 3.0)
delayed_job_active_record (0.3.2)
  activerecord (> 2.1.0)
  delayed_job (~> 3.0.0)
devise (1.5.3)
  bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
  orm_adapter (~> 0.0.3)
  warden (~> 1.1)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.2.13)
  multi_json (~> 1.0)
factory_girl (1.3.3)
factory_girl_rails (1.0)
  factory_girl (~> 1.3)
  rails (>= 3.0.0.beta4)
fastercsv (1.5.4)
formtastic (1.2.4)
  actionpack (>= 2.3.7)
  activesupport (>= 2.3.7)
  i18n (~> 0.4)
gravatar_image_tag (1.0.0.pre2)
has_scope (0.5.1)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
inherited_resources (1.2.2)
  has_scope (~> 0.5.0)
  responders (~> 0.6.0)
jquery-rails (1.0.19)
  railties (~> 3.0)
  thor (~> 0.14)
json (1.6.4)
jwt (0.1.4)
  json (>= 1.2.4)
kaminari (0.13.0)
  actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
  railties (>= 3.0.0)
mail (2.3.0)
  i18n (>= 0.4.0)
  mime-types (~> 1.16)
  treetop (~> 1.4.8)
meta_search (1.1.1)
  actionpack (~> 3.1.0)
  activerecord (~> 3.1.0)
  activesupport (~> 3.1.0)
  polyamorous (~> 0.5.0)
mime-types (1.17.2)
multi_json (1.0.4)
nokogiri (1.5.0)
nokogiri (1.5.0-x86-mingw32)
orm_adapter (0.0.6)
pg (0.13.2)
polyamorous (0.5.0)
  activerecord (~> 3.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.3.6)
rack-cache (1.1)
  rack (>= 0.4)
rack-mount (0.8.3)
  rack (>= 1.0.0)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
  rack
rack-test (0.6.1)
  rack (>= 1.0)
rails (3.1.1)
  actionmailer (= 3.1.1)
  actionpack (= 3.1.1)
  activerecord (= 3.1.1)
  activeresource (= 3.1.1)
  activesupport (= 3.1.1)
  bundler (~> 1.0)
  railties (= 3.1.1)
railties (3.1.1)
  actionpack (= 3.1.1)
  activesupport (= 3.1.1)
  rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
  rake (>= 0.8.7)
  rdoc (~> 3.4)
  thor (~> 0.14.6)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12)
  json (~> 1.4)
responders (0.6.4)
rspec (2.6.0)
  rspec-core (~> 2.6.0)
  rspec-expectations (~> 2.6.0)
  rspec-mocks (~> 2.6.0)
rspec-core (2.6.4)
rspec-expectations (2.6.0)
  diff-lcs (~> 1.1.2)
rspec-mocks (2.6.0)
rspec-rails (2.6.1)
  actionpack (~> 3.0)
  activesupport (~> 3.0)
  railties (~> 3.0)
  rspec (~> 2.6.0)
sass (3.1.12)
sass-rails (3.1.5)
  actionpack (~> 3.1.0)
  railties (~> 3.1.0)
  sass (~> 3.1.10)
  tilt (~> 1.3.2)
spork (0.9.0.rc8)
spork (0.9.0.rc8-x86-mingw32)
  win32-process
sprockets (2.0.3)
  hike (~> 1.2)
  rack (~> 1.0)
  tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
  polyglot
  polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
turn (0.8.3)
  ansi
twilio-ruby (3.5.1)
  builder (>= 2.1.2)
  jwt (>= 0.1.2)
  multi_json (>= 1.0.3)
tzinfo (0.3.31)
uglifier (1.2.1)
  execjs (>= 0.3.0)
  multi_json (>= 1.0.2)
warden (1.1.0)
  rack (>= 1.0)
webrat (0.7.1)
  nokogiri (>= 1.2.0)
  rack (>= 1.0)
  rack-test (>= 0.5.3)
whenever (0.7.2)
  activesupport (>= 2.3.4)
  chronic (~> 0.6.3)
win32-api (1.4.8-x86-mingw32)
win32-process (0.6.5)
  windows-pr (>= 1.1.2)
windows-api (0.4.0)
  win32-api (>= 1.4.5)
windows-pr (1.2.1)
  win32-api (>= 1.4.5)
  windows-api (>= 0.3.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby
  x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  activeadmin
  annotate (= 2.4.0)
  builder
  coffee-rails (~> 3.1.1)
  daemons
  delayed_job_active_record
  factory_girl_rails (= 1.0)
  gravatar_image_tag (= 1.0.0.pre2)
  jquery-rails
  pg
  rails (= 3.1.1)
  rspec-rails (= 2.6.1)
  sass-rails (~> 3.1.4)
  spork (= 0.9.0.rc8)
  turn
  twilio-ruby
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
  webrat (= 0.7.1)
  whenever
```

Yet, when I do git push heroku master, I get

```
Installing sqlite3 (1.3.4) with native extensions Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please report this error to the Bundler issue tracker at https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues so that we can fix it. Thanks!
```

And as you can see, disaster strikes.

Ok, that's it.  If you can help me, I will be oh so happy.

Jeff

Comment: Are your new versions of `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` checked into git?

Comment: @matt, you need to make this the answer! SMH!! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

1. Open `database.yml` & verify that adapter is *NOT* sqlite3 for development,test & production.
2. try running the following commands

   `$ bundle install`  #this would regenerate your gemfile.lock

   `$ rake db:create`

   `$ rake db:scheme:load`

   `$ rake db:migrate`

3.now try deployment again, if it doesn't still work. run `heroku logs` & post back the results